# Footer Longtable alignment

Tags: tables, longtable

I am trying to get the text below longtable to have the same spacing as normal tables (as you can see, as for my example, the spacing is quite big (due to the fact, I added it as multirow text?) (I am using LuaLatex btw in case that matters)[image: longtable][image: normal table]

Is there a way to get it the same as normal tables?

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LAYOUT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
  headings=standardclasses,
  listof=totoc,
  numbers=noenddot
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=2.50cm, bottom=2.00cm, footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TABLES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{longtable}% longtables 
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{subcaption,booktabs}
\usepackage{arydshln}% draw dash-lines in tables
\setlength\dashlinedash{0.2pt}
\setlength\dashlinegap{1.5pt}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.3pt}
\usepackage{diagbox}% diagonal box
\usepackage{multirow}% multirow for diagonal box 
\usepackage{tikz}% tikz
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,fit,positioning,shapes.symbols,chains}
%\usepackage{ltablex}
%\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MAIN
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
\caption{TableA}\label{ta:ta1}
\centering
\begin{tabular}[htb]{l} 
\toprule
\textbf{TableA}  \\ 
\midrule
a                                      \\ \hdashline
b                                   \\ \hdashline
c                           \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\\Quelle: Eigene Darstellung\\
\end{table}
    
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
\addtolength{\extrarowheight}{\aboverulesep}
\addtolength{\extrarowheight}{\belowrulesep}
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\ADLnullwidehline

\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt} % default: 6pt

\begin{longtable}{llp{3cm}l}
\caption{Übersicht des historischen Korpus (CHJ) von Chunagon}\label{ta:choverview}\\
\toprule
Epoche      & Periode         & Korpora     & Einordnung    \\  
\midrule
\endhead

\bottomrule
\multicolumn{4}{p{\textwidth}}{\begin{center}Quelle: CHJ.2009\\
(Eigene Darstellung) \end{center}}
\endlastfoot

Altertum    & Nara            & Man’y\={o}sh\={u}               & Gedicht- und Liederanthologie \\ \cdashline{3-4}
            &                 & Norito                  & Ritualisierte shint\={o}. Gebete  \\ \cdashline{3-4}
            &                 & Senmy\={o}                  & Gesetzestexte                 \\ \cline{2-4}
            & Heian           & Monogatari              & Fiktive Erzählung (Märchen)   \\ \cdashline{3-4}
            &                 & Nikki                   & Tagebuchliteratur             \\ \hline
Mittelalter & Kamakura        & Kaid\={o}ki                 & Reiseliteratur                \\ \cdashline{3-4}
            &                 & Nikki                   & Tagebuchliteratur             \\ \cdashline{3-4}
            &                 & Zuihitsu                & Miszellenliteratur            \\ \cline{2-4}
            & Muromachi       & Ky\={o}gen                  & Theater-Form                  \\ \cdashline{3-4}
            &                 & Kirishitan Shiry\={o}       & Christliche Literatur         \\ \hline
Neuzeit     & Edo             & Kaid\={o}ki                 & Reiseliteratur                \\ \cdashline{3-4}
            &                 & Nikki                   & Tagebuchliteratur             \\ \cdashline{3-4}
            &                 & Zuihitsu                & Miszellenliteratur            \\ \cdashline{3-4}
            &                 & Share-bon               & Form der Komödie              \\ \cdashline{3-4}
            &                 & Ninj\={o}-bon               & Romantische Literatur         \\ \cline{2-4}
Moderne     & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Meiji \&\\ Taishō\end{tabular}} & Zasshi                  & Zeitschriften                 \\ \cdashline{3-4}
            &                 & Ky\={o}kasho                & Schulbücher                   \\ \cdashline{3-4}
            &                 & Meiji-shoki-k\={o}go Shiry\={o} & Sammlung gesprochener Sprache \\ \cdashline{3-4}
            &                 & Kindai sh\={o}setsu         & Moderne Romane           \\                         
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remove from your document example all not used settings and wrong inserted `\\` , than I get the following result:

[image]

Is above result what you after?

In MWE (Minimal Working example I use `xltabular` instead of `longtable`, for multiline text cell I use `makecell` package:

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
  headings=standardclasses,
  listof=totoc,
  numbers=noenddot
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[hmargin=2.50cm, 
            vmargin={2.50cm, 2.00cm}, 
            footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[main=ngerman, english]{babel}

% tables
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, xltabular}
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hsize=#1\hsize}X}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.15pt}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\arrayrulecolor{gray}

%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\caption{TableA}
\label{ta:ta1}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}[htb]{l}
    \toprule
\textbf{Table A}    \\
    \midrule
a                   \\ \hdashline
b                   \\ \hdashline
c                   \\
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\end{tabular}

\small
Quelle: Eigene Darstellung\\
    \end{table}

\lipsum[66]

\begingroup
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}% default: 6pt
    \begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{ll L{0.9}L{1.1}}
\caption{Übersicht des historischen Korpus (CHJ) von Chunagon}
\label{ta:choverview}\\
    \toprule
Epoche  & Periode   & Korpora   & Einordnung        \\
    \midrule
\endhead
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{4}{p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}{\centering\small
                               Quelle: CHJ.2009\\
                               (Eigene Darstellung)}
\endlastfoot
% table body
Altertum    & Nara  & Man’y\={o}sh\={u} & Gedicht- und Liederanthologie     \\
    \cdashline{3-4}
            &       & Norito            & Ritualisierte shint\={o}. Gebete  \\
    \cdashline{3-4}
            &           & Senmy\={o}    & Gesetzestexte                     \\
    \cline{2-4}
            & Heian & Monogatari        & Fiktive Erzählung (Märchen)       \\
    \cdashline{3-4}
            &       & Nikki             & Tagebuchliteratur                 \\ 
    \midrule
Mittelalter & Kamakura  & Kaid\={o}ki   & Reiseliteratur                    \\
    \cdashline{3-4}
            &       & Nikki             & Tagebuchliteratur                 \\
    \cdashline{3-4}
            &       & Zuihitsu          & Miszellenliteratur                \\ 
    \cmidrule{2-4}
            & Muromachi & Ky\={o}gen    & Theater-Form                      \\
    \cdashline{3-4}
            &   & Kirishitan Shiry\={o} & Christliche Literatur             \\ 
    \midrule
Neuzeit     & Edo   & Kaid\={o}ki       & Reiseliteratur                    \\
    \cdashline{3-4}
            &       & Nikki             & Tagebuchliteratur                 \\
    \cdashline{3-4}
            &       & Zuihitsu          & Miszellenliteratur                \\        
    \cdashline{3-4}
            &       & Share-bon         & Form der Komödie                  \\
    \cdashline{3-4}
            &       & Ninj\={o}-bon     & Romantische Literatur             \\
    \cmidrule{2-4}
Moderne     & \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{Meiji\\ Taishō}}
                    & Zasshi            & Zeitschriften                     \\
    \cdashline{3-4}
            &       & Ky\={o}kasho      & Schulbücher                       \\
    \cdashline{3-4}
            &       & Meiji-shoki-k\={o}go Shiry\={o} 
                                        & Sammlung gesprochener Sprache     \\
    \cdashline{3-4}
            &   & Kindai sh\={o}setsu   & Moderne Romane                    \\
    \end{xltabular}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

As you can see, solid horizontal lines in table are not equal. Is this intentional? Anyway, I would remove almost all horizontal lines in table:

[image]

In the MWE, by which is produced above image, is more complete as in the first example. It is extended so, that in the case, if `xltabular` is really needed (it span two or more pages) it repeat captions and column headers on all pages:

**Edit:**
Ups, I forgot to upload code for the second example:

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
  headings=standardclasses,
  listof=totoc,
  numbers=noenddot
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[hmargin=2.50cm, 
            vmargin={2.50cm, 2.00cm}, 
            footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[main=ngerman, english]{babel}

% tables
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, xltabular}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hsize=#1\hsize}X}

%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\caption{TableA}
\label{ta:ta1}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}[htb]{l}
    \toprule
\textbf{Table A}    \\
    \midrule
a                   \\ 
b                   \\ 
c                   \\
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\end{tabular}

\small
Quelle: Eigene Darstellung\\
    \end{table}

\lipsum[1]

\begingroup
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}% default: 6pt
\makegapedcells
    \begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{ll L{0.9}L{1.1}}
\caption{Übersicht des historischen Korpus (CHJ) von Chunagon}
\label{ta:choverview}\\
    \toprule
Epoche  & Periode   & Korpora   & Einordnung        \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{Übersicht des historischen Korpus (CHJ) von Chunagon}
\label{ta:choverview}\\
    \toprule
Epoche  & Periode   & Korpora   & Einordnung        \\
    \midrule
\endhead
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    \multicolumn{4}{r}{\small\textit{Continue on the next page}}
\endfoot
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{4}{p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}{\centering\small
                               Quelle: CHJ.2009\\
                               (Eigene Darstellung)}
\endlastfoot
% table body
Altertum    & Nara  & Man’y\={o}sh\={u} & Gedicht- und Liederanthologie     \\           
            &       & Norito            & Ritualisierte shint\={o}. Gebete  \\
            &           & Senmy\={o}    & Gesetzestexte                     \\
    \addlinespace
            & Heian & Monogatari        & Fiktive Erzählung (Märchen)       \\
            &       & Nikki             & Tagebuchliteratur                 \\ 
    \addlinespace
Mittelalter & Kamakura  & Kaid\={o}ki   & Reiseliteratur                    \\
            &       & Nikki             & Tagebuchliteratur                 \\
            &       & Zuihitsu          & Miszellenliteratur                \\ 
            & Muromachi & Ky\={o}gen    & Theater-Form                      \\
            &   & Kirishitan Shiry\={o} & Christliche Literatur             \\ 
    \addlinespace
Neuzeit     & Edo   & Kaid\={o}ki       & Reiseliteratur                    \\
            &       & Nikki             & Tagebuchliteratur                 \\
            &       & Zuihitsu          & Miszellenliteratur                \\        
            &       & Share-bon         & Form der Komödie                  \\
            &       & Ninj\={o}-bon     & Romantische Literatur             \\
    \addlinespace
Moderne     & \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{Meiji\\ Taishō}}
                    & Zasshi            & Zeitschriften                     \\
            &       & Ky\={o}kasho      & Schulbücher                       \\
            &       & Meiji-shoki-k\={o}go Shiry\={o} 
                                        & Sammlung gesprochener Sprache     \\
            &   & Kindai sh\={o}setsu   & Moderne Romane                    \\
    \end{xltabular}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:** An example, where for long table is also used `threeparttable`, which enable add nicer notes about table's data source. IN MWE is consider only long table:

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
  headings=standardclasses,
  listof=totoc,
  numbers=noenddot
]{scrartcl}
% pagelayout
\usepackage[hmargin=2.50cm, 
            vmargin={2.50cm, 2.00cm}, 
            footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[main=ngerman, english]{babel}
% tables
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, xltabular}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hsize=#1\hsize}X}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]

\begingroup
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}% default: 6pt
\makegapedcells
\begin{ThreePartTable}
    \setTableNoteFont{\color{gray}\footnotesize\vspace*{-0.5ex}}
\begin{TableNotes}[para,raggedright]\smallskip
\source{\textcolor{gray}{CHJ.2009 (Eigene Darstellung)}}
\end{TableNotes}
    \begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{ll L{0.9}L{1.1}}
\caption{Übersicht des historischen Korpus (CHJ) von Chunagon}
\label{ta:choverview}\\
    \toprule
Epoche  & Periode   & Korpora   & Einordnung        \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{Übersicht des historischen Korpus (CHJ) von Chunagon}
\label{ta:choverview}\\
    \toprule
Epoche  & Periode   & Korpora   & Einordnung        \\
    \midrule
\endhead
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    \multicolumn{4}{r}{\small\textit{Continue on the next page}}
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
    \insertTableNotes\\
\endlastfoot
% table body
Altertum    & Nara  & Man’y\={o}sh\={u} & Gedicht- und Liederanthologie     \\           
            &       & Norito            & Ritualisierte shint\={o}. Gebete  \\
            &           & Senmy\={o}    & Gesetzestexte                     \\
    \addlinespace
            & Heian & Monogatari        & Fiktive Erzählung (Märchen)       \\
            &       & Nikki             & Tagebuchliteratur                 \\ 
    \addlinespace
Mittelalter & Kamakura  & Kaid\={o}ki   & Reiseliteratur                    \\
            &       & Nikki             & Tagebuchliteratur                 \\
            &       & Zuihitsu          & Miszellenliteratur                \\ 
            & Muromachi & Ky\={o}gen    & Theater-Form                      \\
            &   & Kirishitan Shiry\={o} & Christliche Literatur             \\ 
    \addlinespace
Neuzeit     & Edo   & Kaid\={o}ki       & Reiseliteratur                    \\
            &       & Nikki             & Tagebuchliteratur                 \\
            &       & Zuihitsu          & Miszellenliteratur                \\        
            &       & Share-bon         & Form der Komödie                  \\
            &       & Ninj\={o}-bon     & Romantische Literatur             \\
    \addlinespace
Moderne     & \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{Meiji\\ Taishō}}
                    & Zasshi            & Zeitschriften                     \\
            &       & Ky\={o}kasho      & Schulbücher                       \\
            &       & Meiji-shoki-k\={o}go Shiry\={o} 
                                        & Sammlung gesprochener Sprache     \\
            &   & Kindai sh\={o}setsu   & Moderne Romane                    \\
    \end{xltabular}
\end{ThreePartTable}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Hm so I have to completely change packages again right? Solid lines are set as per booktabs (toprule/midrule/bottomrule). I was under the assumption this would make it more readable.

Comment: What does \begingroup
\setlength\LTleft{0pt} do? @Zarko

Comment: @user236381, I nothing change again. I only make your MWE compilable  and solve your problem. It is true, that I took a liberty and show you, how I would design your table.  With `\begingroup` ... `\endgroup` is limited local settings for long table (used `xltabular`). `LT\left` is table distance from left side of text area on page. For details see docuentation for `longtable` and `xltabule` (which combine `longtable` and `tabularx`).

Comment: Thank you! I will try to modify!

Comment: Hm.. for me the text below is still different (although I was able to reduce some space thanks to you! Also, for me it won't show the "to be continued" part actually). Will try to solve

Comment: Text regarding comment to table is copied from your MWE, added note *Continue on the next page* will appear, if table is longer than (rest of) page where it is inserted. If the text is not such as you wish to have, please correct it}. BTW, I would add *Source: ...* as one line text, with smaller gray font (see addendum to my answer, will appear soon)