# longtable to xltabular change

Tags: tables, longtable, xltabular

I have tried to adjust my longtables as xltabular as per [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/602178/footer-longtable-alignment/602193?noredirect=1#comment1510365_602193) advise.
However, this seems t o interfere with some of my setups.
(I am using lualatex)

1. the background color for tables now missing
2. formatting of table exceeding limits

before (longtable): [image: previous longtable format]

now (xltabular): [image: current xltabular format]

Also, I am still curious, why the spacing between the first normal table and the text below "Quelle..." is different from the ones in the xltabulars.

[image: 1][image]

Anyone having any advice?
Thanks in advance!
(Since I am using multiple packages for table environment that also may interfere with each other I added them to the MWE (e.g. xcolor, which I also need for non-table environment and which interfered with arydshln before, if I didn't set it above arydshln.)

MWE

```
 \documentclass[
      12pt,
      a4paper,
      headings=standardclasses,
      listof=totoc,
      numbers=noenddot
    ]{scrartcl}
    
\usepackage[hmargin=2.50cm, 
            vmargin={2.50cm, 2.00cm}, 
            footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[main=ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[match]{luatexja-preset}% Japanese
\usepackage{floatrow}% sf
\floatsetup[table]{font=sf,capposition=top}% table sf
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont=sf,font=sf}
\floatsetup[figure]{font=sf,capposition=top}% figure sf
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=sf,font=sf}
% tables
\usepackage{xcolor}% mark text must be above arydshln
\usepackage{colortbl}
%\usepackage{longtable}% longtables 
\usepackage{array,booktabs,makecell,multirow,subcaption,xltabular}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hsize=#1\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{arydshln}% draw dash-lines in tables
\setlength\dashlinedash{0.2pt}
\setlength\dashlinegap{1.5pt}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.3pt}
\usepackage{diagbox}% diagonal box
\usepackage{tikz}% tikz
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,fit,positioning,shapes.symbols,chains}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\caption{TableA}
\label{ta:ta1}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}[htb]{l}
    \toprule
\textbf{Table A}    \\
    \midrule
a                   \\ 
b                   \\ 
c                   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\\Quelle: Eigene Darstellung\\
    \end{table}

\lipsum[1]

\begingroup
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}% default: 6pt
\makegapedcells
    \begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{ll L{0.9}L{1.1}}
\caption{Übersicht des historischen Korpus (CHJ) von Chunagon}
\label{ta:choverview}\\
    \toprule
Epoche  & Periode   & Korpora   & Einordnung        \\
\midrule
\endhead
    \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{4}{r}{\small\textit{weiter auf der nächsten Seite}}
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
\multicolumn{4}{p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}{\centering\small
                               Quelle: CHJ.2009\\
                               (Eigene Darstellung)}
\endlastfoot
% table body
Altertum    & Nara  & Man’y\={o}sh\={u} & Gedicht- und Liederanthologie     \\           
            &       & Norito            & Ritualisierte shint\={o}. Gebete  \\
            &           & Senmy\={o}    & Gesetzestexte                     \\
    \addlinespace
            & Heian & Monogatari        & Fiktive Erzählung (Märchen)       \\
            &       & Nikki             & Tagebuchliteratur                 \\ 
    \addlinespace
Mittelalter & Kamakura  & Kaid\={o}ki   & Reiseliteratur                    \\
            &       & Nikki             & Tagebuchliteratur                 \\
            &       & Zuihitsu          & Miszellenliteratur                \\ 
            & Muromachi & Ky\={o}gen    & Theater-Form                      \\
            &   & Kirishitan Shiry\={o} & Christliche Literatur             \\ 
    \addlinespace
Neuzeit     & Edo   & Kaid\={o}ki       & Reiseliteratur                    \\
            &       & Nikki             & Tagebuchliteratur                 \\
            &       & Zuihitsu          & Miszellenliteratur                \\        
            &       & Share-bon         & Form der Komödie                  \\
            &       & Ninj\={o}-bon     & Romantische Literatur             \\
    \addlinespace
Moderne     & \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{Meiji\\ Taishō}}
                    & Zasshi            & Zeitschriften                     \\
            &       & Ky\={o}kasho      & Schulbücher                       \\
            &       & Meiji-shoki-k\={o}go Shiry\={o} 
                                        & Sammlung gesprochener Sprache     \\
            &   & Kindai sh\={o}setsu   & Moderne Romane                    \\
    \end{xltabular}
\endgroup
%
\begingroup
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}% default: 6pt
\makegapedcells
    \begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{ll >{\raggedright}p{2.5cm} >{\raggedright}p{3cm} cr}
\caption{Kollokationen von 禍}\label{ta:collka} \\
    \toprule
\textbf{Syntax} & \textbf{Kollokation} & \textbf{Kana} & 
\textbf{Translat} & \textbf{Frequenz} & \textbf{Score}  \\ 
    \midrule
\endhead
    \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{4}{r}{\small\textit{weiter auf der nächsten Seite}}
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
\multicolumn{4}{p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}{\centering\small
                               Quelle: CHJ.2009\\
                               (Eigene Darstellung)}
\endlastfoot
% table body
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.937,0.937,0.937} wo + Verb & &  & & 15  & 11,0 \\ 
  & 転ずる  & tenzuru & wenden & 11  & 11,8 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 及ぼす  & oyobosu & ausüben & 4 & 10,2 \\ 
\rowcolor[rgb]{0.937,0.937,0.937} Pron. + no & &  & & 23  & 10,2 \\ 

  & 鳥 & tori  & Vogel  & 2 & 11,1 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 洪水   & k\={o}zui & Überschwemmung & 2 & 10,9 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 虫 & mushi & Insekt & 1 & 10,3 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 人滿   &  & Menschenmenge & 1 & 10,2 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 所謂政教混乱 & iwayuru seiky\={o} konran & s.\ g.\ politisch-religiöse Verwirrung  & 1 & 10,2 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 生民   & seimin  & Volk   & 1 & 10,2 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 子孫赤族 & shison aka-zoku  & Nachkomme der Akha  & 1 & 10,2 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 破船   & hasen & Schiffbruch  & 1 & 10,2 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 国家党人 & kokka t\={o}jin & Parteimitglied & 1 & 10,2 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 東夷北狄 & t\={o}i hokuteki & Dongyi und Beidi~(indigene Völker Chinas)  & 1 & 10,2 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 連累   & renrui  & Mitschuld  & 1 & 10,2 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 江浙   & k\={o}nan & Jiangzhe~(hist. Region Chinas, ca.\ 1276--1299) & 1 & 10,2 \\ 
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 文字   & moji  & Schrift(zeichen) & 1 & 10,2 \\ 
    \end{xltabular}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

---

Updated my MWE as per advice:

```
  \begin{document}

% random highlighted text
\colorbox{lightgray}{i am gray}
%table 1
 \begin{table}[htb]
\caption{TableA}
\label{ta:ta1}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}[htb]{l}
    \toprule
\textbf{Table A}    \\
    \midrule
a                   \\ 
b                   \\ 
c                   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\\Quelle: Eigene Darstellung\\
    \end{table}

%table 2
\begingroup
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}% default: 6pt
\makegapedcells
    \begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{lcll}
\caption{Übersicht des historischen Korpus (CHJ) von Chunagon}
\label{ta:choverview}\\
    \toprule
Epoche  & Periode   & Korpora   & Einordnung        \\
\midrule
\endhead
    \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{4}{r}{\small\textit{weiter auf der nächsten Seite}}
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
\multicolumn{4}{p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}{\centering\small
                               Quelle: CHJ.2009\\
                               (Eigene Darstellung)}
\endlastfoot
% table body
Altertum    & Nara  & Man’y\={o}sh\={u} & Gedicht- und Liederanthologie     \\           
            &       & Norito            & Ritualisierte shint\={o}. Gebete  \\
            &           & Senmy\={o}    & Gesetzestexte                     \\
    \addlinespace
            & Heian & Monogatari        & Fiktive Erzählung (Märchen)       \\
            &       & Nikki             & Tagebuchliteratur                 \\ 
    \addlinespace
        \midrule
Mittelalter & Kamakura  & Kaid\={o}ki   & Reiseliteratur                    \\
            &       & Nikki             & Tagebuchliteratur                 \\
            &       & Zuihitsu          & Miszellenliteratur                \\ 
            & Muromachi & Ky\={o}gen    & Theater-Form                      \\
            &   & Kirishitan Shiry\={o} & Christliche Literatur             \\ 
    \addlinespace
        \midrule
Neuzeit     & Edo   & Kaid\={o}ki       & Reiseliteratur                    \\
            &       & Nikki             & Tagebuchliteratur                 \\
            &       & Zuihitsu          & Miszellenliteratur                \\        
            &       & Share-bon         & Form der Komödie                  \\
            &       & Ninj\={o}-bon     & Romantische Literatur             \\
    \addlinespace
        \midrule
Moderne     & \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{Meiji\\ Taishō}}
                    & Zasshi            & Zeitschriften                     \\
            &       & Ky\={o}kasho      & Schulbücher                       \\
            &       & Meiji-shoki-k\={o}go Shiry\={o} 
                                        & Sammlung gesprochener Sprache     \\
            &   & Kindai sh\={o}setsu   & Moderne Romane                    \\
    \end{xltabular}
\endgroup
% table 3

\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{ll >{\raggedright}p{2.8cm}L cr}
\caption{Kollokationen von 禍}\\
    \toprule
\textbf{Syntax}
    & \textbf{Kollokation}
        & \textbf{Kana}
            & \textbf{Translat}
                & \textbf{Freq.}
                    & \textbf{Score}        \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{Kollokationen von 禍 \qquad(cont.)}\\
\textbf{Syntax}
    & \textbf{Kollokation}
        & \textbf{Kana}
            & \textbf{Translat}
                & \textbf{Freq.}
                    & \textbf{Score}        \\
    \midrule
\endhead
%    \midrule
    \multicolumn{6}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{weiter auf der nächsten Seite}}
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
\endlastfoot
    \rowcolor{gray!20}
wo + Verb
    &       &       &       & 15    & 11,0  \\
    & 及ぼす  & oyobosu
                    & ausüben
                            & 4     & 10,2  \\
    \cdashline{2-6}
    & 鳥      & tori   & Vogel  & 2     & 11,1 \\
        \cdashline{2-6}
    & 洪水   & kōzui & Überschwemmung
                            & 2     & 10,9 \\
    \cdashline{2-6}
    & 虫     & mushi & Insekt  & 1     & 10,3 \\
    \cdashline{2-6}
  & 人滿    &      & Menschenmenge
                            & 1     & 10,2 \\
    \cdashline{2-6}
  & 所謂政教混乱
        & iwayuru seikyō konran
                & s.\ g.\ politisch-religiöse Verwirrung
                            & 1     & 10,2 \\
    \cdashline{2-6}
  & 生民   & seimin & Volk    & 1     & 10,2 \\
    \cdashline{2-6}
  & 子孫赤族
        & shison aka-zoku
                & Nachkomme der Akha
                            & 1     & 10,2 \\
    \cdashline{2-6}
  & 破船 & hasen & Schiffbruch
                            & 1     & 10,2 \\
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 国家党人
        & kokka tōjin
                & Parteimitglied
                            & 1     & 10,2 \\
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 東夷北狄
        & tōi hokuteki
                & Dongyi und Beidi (indigene Völker Chinas)
                            & 1     & 10,2 \\
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 連累   & renrui
                & Mitschuld & 1     & 10,2 \\
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 江浙   & kōnan & Jiangzhe (hist. Region Chinas, ca. 1276--1299)
                            & 1     & 10,2 \\
    \cdashline{2-6}
  & 文字   & moji  & Schrift (zeichen) & 1 & 10,2 \\
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 代々弑殺 & daidai shīsatsu  & & 1 & 10,2 \\
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 滔天   & tōten & Tōten (pol. Aktivist, $\approx$ 1871--1922) & 1 & 10,1 \\
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 宦者   & kanja & Eunuch & 1 & 10,1 \\
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 不思議  & fushigi & Mysterium  & 1 & 10,1 \\
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 先達て  & sakidachite & zuvor  & 1 & 10,1 \\
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 外寇   & gaikō & Invasion   & 1 & 10,1 \\
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 孛佛兵争 & haifutsu heisō & Deutsch-Französischer Krieg (1870--1871) & 1 & 10,1 \\
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 人為   & jin'i & menschliches Tun & 1 & 10,1 \\

    \rowcolor{gray!20}
ni + Verb
  &         &   &   & 10    & 10,8  \\
  & 逢う   & au & sich begegnen & 3 & 11,5 \\
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 罹る   & kakaru  & erleiden   & 4 & 11,2 \\
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 堪ざる  & koezaru & (nicht) aushalten & 1 & 10,7 \\
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 陥る   & ochiiru & in etw. (ver)fallen & 1 & 10,5 \\
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 當る   & ataru & treffen & 1 & 10,3 \\

    \rowcolor{gray!20}
wa + Verb
    &   &       &           & 11  & 10,8 \\
  & 起こる  & okoru & sich ereignen & 4 & 11,9 \\
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 伏蔵為る & fukuzō suru & sich verborgen halten & 1 & 10,9 \\
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 有る得る & arueru  & möglich sein & 1 & 10,8 \\
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 局為る  & kyokusuru & begrenzen  & 1 & 10,8 \\
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 及ぶ   & oyobu & sich erstrecken  & 2 & 10,7 \\
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 避ける  & sakeru  & (ver)meiden  & 1 & 10,5 \\
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 関する  & kansuru & betreffen  & 1 & 10,2 \\

    \rowcolor{gray!20}
Adn
  &         &           &   & 1 & 10,6 \\
  & 然したる        & sashitaru & nicht sonderlich   & 1 & 10,9 \\

    \rowcolor{gray!20}
no + Pron. 
  &         &           &   & 7 & 7,1 \\
  & 門 & monkado & Tor    & 3 & 12,3 \\
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 根源   & kongen  & Ursprung   & 1 & 10,4 \\
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 身 & mi & Körper & 1 & 10,4 \\

    \rowcolor{gray!20}
Kompositum
    &   &   &   & 1 & 13,4 \\
  & 仏郎察  & futsu rō satsu & Frankreich & 1 & 13,4 \\
\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

**Open Questions:**
a) Here, the alignment of "weiter zur nächsten Seite.." (continued on next page) is not correct.
How do I fix it?
[image]
b) Also: the xltabular seems to ignore the font settings for tables. Can I add a standard (sans serif) to xlatbular too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this? Unfortunately I haven't installed Japan fonts ...

[image]

Above table is obtained by at least two compilation by `LuaLaTeX` of the following MWE_

```
\documentclass[ 12pt,
                a4paper,
                headings=standardclasses,
                listof=totoc,
                numbers=noenddot
              ] {scrartcl}
\usepackage[showframe,
            hmargin=2.5cm,
            vmargin={2.5cm, 2cm},
            footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% languages
\usepackage[main=ngerman, english]{babel}
% fonts
\usepackage{libertine}
%\usepackage{libertinust1math}

% table
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{booktabs, xltabular}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} % default: 6pt
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.15pt}
\arrayrulecolor{gray}

\begin{document}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{ll >{\raggedright}p{2.8cm}L cr}
\caption{Kollokationen von 禍}\\
    \midrule
\textbf{Syntax}
    & \textbf{Kollokation}
        & \textbf{Kana}
            & \textbf{Translat}
                & \textbf{Freq.}
                    & \textbf{Score}        \\
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{Kollokationen von 禍 \qquad(cont.)}\\
\textbf{Syntax}
    & \textbf{Kollokation}
        & \textbf{Kana}
            & \textbf{Translat}
                & \textbf{Freq.}
                    & \textbf{Score}        \\
\endhead
%    \midrule
    \multicolumn{6}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{Continue on the next page}}
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
\endlastfoot
    \rowcolor{gray!30}
wo + Verb
    &       &       &       & 15    & 11,0  \\
    \cdashline{2-6}
    & 及ぼす  & oyobosu
                    & ausüben
                            & 4     & 10,2  \\

    \cdashline{2-6}
    & 鳥      & tori   & Vogel  & 2     & 11,1 \\

    \cdashline{2-6}
    & 洪水   & kōzui & Überschwemmung
                            & 2     & 10,9 \\
    \cdashline{2-6}
    & 虫     & mushi & Insekt  & 1     & 10,3 \\
    \cdashline{2-6}
  & 人滿    &      & Menschenmenge
                            & 1     & 10,2 \\
    \cdashline{2-6}
  & 所謂政教混乱
        & iwayuru seikyō konran
                & s.\ g.\ politisch-religiöse Verwirrung
                            & 1     & 10,2 \\
    \cdashline{2-6}
  & 生民   & seimin & Volk    & 1     & 10,2 \\
  \cdashline{2-6}
  & 子孫赤族
        & shison aka-zoku
                & Nachkomme der Akha
                            & 1     & 10,2 \\
  \cdashline{2-6}
  & 破船 & hasen & Schiffbruch
                            & 1     & 10,2 \\
   \cdashline{2-6}
  & 国家党人
        & kokka tōjin
                & Parteimitglied
                            & 1     & 10,2 \\
\cdashline{2-6}
  & 東夷北狄
        & tōi hokuteki
                & Dongyi und Beidi (indigene Völker Chinas)
                            & 1     & 10,2 \\
  \cdashline{2-6}
  & 連累   & renrui
                & Mitschuld & 1     & 10,2 \\
  \cdashline{2-6}
  & 江浙   & kōnan & Jiangzhe (hist. Region Chinas, ca. 1276--1299)
                            & 1     & 10,2 \\
  \cdashline{2-6}
  & 文字   & moji  & Schrift (zeichen) & 1 & 10,2 \\
  \cdashline{2-6}
  & 代々弑殺 & daidai shīsatsu  & & 1 & 10,2 \\
  \cdashline{2-6}
  & 滔天   & tōten & Tōten (pol. Aktivist, $\approx$ 1871--1922) & 1 & 10,1 \\
  \cdashline{2-6}
  & 宦者   & kanja & Eunuch & 1 & 10,1 \\
  \cdashline{2-6}
  & 不思議  & fushigi & Mysterium  & 1 & 10,1 \\
  \cdashline{2-6}
  & 先達て  & sakidachite & zuvor  & 1 & 10,1 \\
  \cdashline{2-6}
  & 外寇   & gaikō & Invasion   & 1 & 10,1 \\
  \cdashline{2-6}
  & 孛佛兵争 & haifutsu heisō & Deutsch-Französischer Krieg (1870--1871) & 1 & 10,1 \\
  \cdashline{2-6}
  & 人為   & jin'i & menschliches Tun & 1 & 10,1 \\

  \rowcolor{gray!30}
ni + Verb
  &         &   &   & 10    & 10,8  \\
  & 逢う   & au & sich begegnen & 3 & 11,5 \\
  \cdashline{2-6}
  & 罹る   & kakaru  & erleiden   & 4 & 11,2 \\
  \cdashline{2-6}
  & 堪ざる  & koezaru & (nicht) aushalten & 1 & 10,7 \\
  \cdashline{2-6}
  & 陥る   & ochiiru & in etw. (ver)fallen & 1 & 10,5 \\
  \cdashline{2-6}
  & 當る   & ataru & treffen & 1 & 10,3 \\

  \rowcolor{gray!30}
wa + Verb
    &   &       &           & 11  & 10,8 \\
  & 起こる  & okoru & sich ereignen & 4 & 11,9 \\
  \cdashline{2-6}
  & 伏蔵為る & fukuzō suru & sich verborgen halten & 1 & 10,9 \\
  \cdashline{2-6}
  & 有る得る & arueru  & möglich sein & 1 & 10,8 \\
  \cdashline{2-6}
  & 局為る  & kyokusuru & begrenzen  & 1 & 10,8 \\
  \cdashline{2-6}
  & 及ぶ   & oyobu & sich erstrecken  & 2 & 10,7 \\
  \cdashline{2-6}
  & 避ける  & sakeru  & (ver)meiden  & 1 & 10,5 \\
  \cdashline{2-6}
  & 関する  & kansuru & betreffen  & 1 & 10,2 \\

  \rowcolor{gray!30}
Adn
  &         &           &   & 1 & 10,6 \\
  & 然したる        & sashitaru & nicht sonderlich   & 1 & 10,9 \\
  \rowcolor{gray!30}
no + Pronomen
  & 門 & monkado & Tor    & 3 & 12,3 \\
  & 根源   & kongen  & Ursprung   & 1 & 10,4 \\
  \cdashline{2-6}
  & 身 & mi & Körper & 1 & 10,4 \\

  \rowcolor{gray!30}
Kompositum
    &   &   &   & 1 & 13,4 \\
  & 仏郎察  & futsu rō satsu & Frankreich & 1 & 13,4 \\
\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

Note: important is order of loading packages related to table. In MWE is considered only long table, small one hasn't problems.

**Addendum:**
rom your comments on answer I conclude, that you like to have main text in serif fonts, text in tables and captions in sans-serif fonts. This can be achieved by use of the `etoolbox` package and settings of use of the `caption` package.

In MWE below are added missed horizontal lines and and inserted `*` after colored  rows terminations. By this table's break is more consistent. Also resulted table hasn't problem with protrusion of its bottoms below text area (see image of table).

```
\documentclass[ 12pt,
                a4paper,
                headings=standardclasses,
                listof=totoc,
                numbers=noenddot
              ] {scrartcl}
\usepackage[showframe,
            hmargin=2.5cm,
            vmargin={2.5cm, 2cm},
            footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% languages
\usepackage[main=ngerman, english]{babel}
% fonts
\usepackage{libertine}
%\usepackage{libertinust1math}

% table
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{booktabs, xltabular}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} % default: 6pt
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.15pt}
\arrayrulecolor{gray}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{xltabular}{\sffamily}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\sffamily}
\usepackage[skip=1ex,
            font={sf,small},
            label font={sf, bf}]{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{ll >{\raggedright}p{2.8cm}L cr}
\caption{Kollokationen von 禍}\\
    \toprule
\textbf{Syntax}
    & \textbf{Kollokation}
        & \textbf{Kana}
            & \textbf{Translat}
                & \textbf{Freq.}
                    & \textbf{Score}        \\
    \specialrule{\heavyrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt} % <----
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{Kollokationen von 禍 \qquad(cont.)}\\
    \toprule
\textbf{Syntax}
    & \textbf{Kollokation}
        & \textbf{Kana}
            & \textbf{Translat}
                & \textbf{Freq.}
                    & \textbf{Score}        \\
    \specialrule{\heavyrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt} % <----
\endhead
    \specialrule{\heavyrulewidth}{-.5pt}{0pt} % <----
    \multicolumn{6}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{Weiter zur nächsten Seite}}
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
\endlastfoot
    \rowcolor{gray!30}
wo + Verb
    &       &       &       & 15    & 11,0  \\* % <----
    \specialrule{0.5\heavyrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt}  % <----
    & 及ぼす  & oyobosu
                    & ausüben
                            & 4     & 10,2  \\

    \cdashline{2-6}
    & 鳥      & tori   & Vogel  & 2     & 11,1 \\

    \cdashline{2-6}
    & 洪水   & kōzui & Überschwemmung
                            & 2     & 10,9 \\
    \cdashline{2-6}
    & 虫     & mushi & Insekt  & 1     & 10,3 \\
    \cdashline{2-6}
  & 人滿    &      & Menschenmenge
                            & 1     & 10,2 \\
    \cdashline{2-6}
  & 所謂政教混乱
        & iwayuru seikyō konran
                & s.\ g.\ politisch-religiöse Verwirrung
                            & 1     & 10,2 \\
    \cdashline{2-6}
  & 生民   & seimin & Volk    & 1     & 10,2 \\
        \cdashline{2-6}
  & 子孫赤族
        & shison aka-zoku
                & Nachkomme der Akha
                            & 1     & 10,2 \\
  \cdashline{2-6}
  & 破船 & hasen & Schiffbruch
                            & 1     & 10,2 \\
    \cdashline{2-6}
  & 国家党人
        & kokka tōjin
                & Parteimitglied
                            & 1     & 10,2 \\
    \cdashline{2-6}
  & 東夷北狄
        & tōi hokuteki
                & Dongyi und Beidi (indigene Völker Chinas)
                            & 1     & 10,2 \\
    \cdashline{2-6}
  & 連累   & renrui
                & Mitschuld & 1     & 10,2 \\
     \cdashline{2-6}
  & 江浙   & kōnan & Jiangzhe (hist. Region Chinas, ca. 1276--1299)
                            & 1     & 10,2 \\
    \cdashline{2-6}
  & 文字   & moji  & Schrift (zeichen) & 1 & 10,2 \\
  \cdashline{2-6}
  & 代々弑殺 & daidai shīsatsu  & & 1 & 10,2 \\
    \cdashline{2-6}
  & 滔天   & tōten & Tōten (pol. Aktivist, $\approx$ 1871--1922) & 1 & 10,1 \\
    \cdashline{2-6}
  & 宦者   & kanja & Eunuch & 1 & 10,1 \\
    \cdashline{2-6}
  & 不思議  & fushigi & Mysterium  & 1 & 10,1 \\
    \cdashline{2-6}
  & 先達て  & sakidachite & zuvor  & 1 & 10,1 \\
    \cdashline{2-6}
  & 外寇   & gaikō & Invasion   & 1 & 10,1 \\
    \cdashline{2-6}
  & 孛佛兵争 & haifutsu heisō & Deutsch-Französischer Krieg (1870--1871) & 1 & 10,1 \\
    \cdashline{2-6}
  & 人為   & jin'i & menschliches Tun & 1 & 10,1 \\

    \specialrule{0.5\heavyrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt} % <----
    \rowcolor{gray!30}
ni + Verb
    &       &       &       & 10    & 10,8  \\* % <----
    \specialrule{0.5\heavyrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt} % <----

  & 逢う   & au & sich begegnen & 3 & 11,5 \\
  \cdashline{2-6}
  & 罹る   & kakaru  & erleiden   & 4 & 11,2 \\
  \cdashline{2-6}
  & 堪ざる  & koezaru & (nicht) aushalten & 1 & 10,7 \\
  \cdashline{2-6}
  & 陥る   & ochiiru & in etw. (ver)fallen & 1 & 10,5 \\
  \cdashline{2-6}
  & 當る   & ataru & treffen & 1 & 10,3 \\

  \specialrule{0.5\heavyrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt} % <----
   \rowcolor{gray!30}
wa + Verb
    &       &       &       & 11    & 110,8  \\* % <----
  \specialrule{0.5\heavyrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt}    % <----

  & 起こる  & okoru & sich ereignen & 4 & 11,9 \\
  \cdashline{2-6}
  & 伏蔵為る & fukuzō suru & sich verborgen halten & 1 & 10,9 \\
  \cdashline{2-6}
  & 有る得る & arueru  & möglich sein & 1 & 10,8 \\
  \cdashline{2-6}
  & 局為る  & kyokusuru & begrenzen  & 1 & 10,8 \\
  \cdashline{2-6}
  & 及ぶ   & oyobu & sich erstrecken  & 2 & 10,7 \\
  \cdashline{2-6}
  & 避ける  & sakeru  & (ver)meiden  & 1 & 10,5 \\
  \cdashline{2-6}
  & 関する  & kansuru & betreffen  & 1 & 10,2 \\

    \specialrule{0.5\heavyrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt} % <----
    \rowcolor{gray!30}
Adn
    &       &       &       & 1    & 10,6  \\*  % <----
    \specialrule{0.5\heavyrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt}  % <----

  & 然したる        & sashitaru & nicht sonderlich   & 1 & 10,9 \\

    \specialrule{0.5\heavyrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt}  % <----
    \rowcolor{gray!30}
no + Pronomen
   & 門              & monkado & Tor & 3     & 12,3 \\* % <----
    \specialrule{0.5\heavyrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt}  % <----

   & 根源   & kongen  & Ursprung   & 1 & 10,4 \\
  \cdashline{2-6}
  & 身 & mi & Körper & 1 & 10,4 \\

      \specialrule{0.5\heavyrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt} % <----
      \rowcolor{gray!30}
Kompositum
    &       &       &       & 1     & 13,4  \\* % <----
    \specialrule{0.5\heavyrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt}  % <----

   & 仏郎察  & futsu rō satsu & Frankreich & 1 & 13,4 \\
\end{xltabular}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the advice! Indeed for some very odd reason \usepackage[table]{xcolor} also seems to work in non-table environments (at least in the MWE - not sure about the real-deal aka big boy thesis). So that should work thanks! Two minor additional questions: a) xltabular seems to ignore the table specific font (sansserif) even if I set it. Can I add sans serif as general for xltabular too? b) the alignment of "to be continued" seems to be a bit off to me (see edited question)

Comment: @user236381. it is not clear, what you mean with *general* with sans serif fonts. Just in `xtabular` tables? Or in all tables (in `table` environment? Or general in the document? At the first case add to preamble `\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{xltabular}{\sffamily}`, for cover also the second cas, add to above  `\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\sffamily}`. For the second problem: long tables cannot end exactly at the end of text. Depends on content, it can end before or protrude bottom text border. You can influence on breaking by use of `\\*` which disallows page break at this row.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately etoolbox does not change the caption to sf too right? (only the table itself)

Comment: @user236381, captions have own settings.  You need to adjust it accordingly.. See addendum to answer.